# How to hide rows when count distinct result is 0? (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, metabase

I have this code

```
 SELECT "School"."name" AS "School",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'A') AS "A",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'B') AS "B",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'C') AS "C",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'D') AS "D"
FROM "public"."user_tokens"
LEFT JOIN "public"."users" "User" ON "public"."user_tokens"."user_id" = "User"."id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."user_roles" "User_2" ON "public"."user_tokens"."user_id" = "User_2"."user_id"
LEFT JOIN "public"."roles" "Role" ON "User_2"."role_id" = "Role"."id" LEFT JOIN "public"."schools" "School" ON "User_2"."school_id" = "School"."id"
GROUP BY "School"."name"
ORDER BY "B" desc
```

The result is like this:

```
  School         A        B        C         D
--------------------------------------------------
    P            5        6       10         6
    Q            1        0        0         0
    R            2        7        0         6
    S            0        8        9         0
```

Is it possible to hide the whole row that contains value '0'? In this case, the result should be School P only.

After that, how to count distinct the "School" that contains no zero value? For this case the result should be 1

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use `having` clause and repeat the expressions

```
having count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'A') > 0 and
       count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'B') > 0 and
       count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'C') > 0 and
       count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'D')
```

Although Postgres allows column aliases in `GROUP BY`, it does not allow expressions on column aliases in the `HAVING` clause (in my opinion, an odd way to extend the SQL standard).

Now, you can also simplify and improve your query.  First, you need matches, so just use `inner join`.  Second, use table aliases.  I'm also getting rid of the double quotes -- those are a really bad idea:

```
 SELECT s.name AS School,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'A') AS A,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'B') AS B,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'C') AS C,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'D') AS D
FROM "public"."user_tokens" ut JOIN
     "public"."users" u
      ON ut.user_id = u.id JOIN
      "public"."user_roles" ur
      ON ut.user_id = ur.user_id JOIN
      "public"."roles" r
      ON ur.role_id = r.id JOIN
      "public"."schools" s
      ON ur.school_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.name
having count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'A') > 0 and
       count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'B') > 0 and
       count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'C') > 0 and
       count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'D') 
ORDER BY "B" desc
```

Comment: ah, that inner join is really a good idea. thanks i'm still learning. 
after this, how to count distinct the "School" that contains no zero value? For this case the result should be 1

Comment: @ettapi . . . You can use this as a subquery and use `count(*)`.  This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you want a more efficient way to get the count, then ask a *new* question  provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
GROUP BY "School"."name"
HAVING count... > 0
      and count... > 0
ORDER BY "B" desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can make the columns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` available for manipulation by enclosing your query as a *table expression* of another `SELECT`. In this outer `SELECT` it's easy to filter out rows by adding the filtering predicate:

```
WHERE "A" <> 0 and "B" <> 0 and "C" <> 0 and "D" <> 0
```

Therefore, your query could look like:

```
SELECT
  *,
  count(*) over() as total_rows
from (
  SELECT "School"."name" AS "School",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'A') AS "A",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'B') AS "B",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'C') AS "C",
        count(distinct "User"."id") filter (where "public"."user_tokens"."app_name" = 'D') AS "D"
  FROM "public"."user_tokens"
  LEFT JOIN "public"."users" "User" ON "public"."user_tokens"."user_id" = "User"."id"
  LEFT JOIN "public"."user_roles" "User_2" ON "public"."user_tokens"."user_id" = "User_2"."user_id"
  LEFT JOIN "public"."roles" "Role" ON "User_2"."role_id" = "Role"."id" LEFT JOIN "public"."schools" "School" ON "User_2"."school_id" = "School"."id"
  GROUP BY "School"."name"
) x
WHERE "A" <> 0 and "B" <> 0 and "C" <> 0 and "D" <> 0
ORDER BY "B" desc
```

This can come in handy for more complex expressions, if you prefer to avoid redundancy of expressions in your query.

Comment: after this, how to count distinct the "School" that contains no 0 value? For this case the result should be 1

Comment: You can add `count(*) over() as total_rows`. See edited query.